# Drools guided decision table: Find which specific condition in rule caused the rule failure.

Tags: drools, kie, kie-workbench

I have used guided decision table from kie-workbench.
This is the rule I have written

```
rule "Row 1 Coupons"
dialect "mvel"
when
    f1 : CartDetails( couponCode == "OS1000" , startDate after "12-Jan-2017" , expiryDate before "31-Jul-2017" , minPurchaseAmt >= 5000.0 , excludeProductCodes excludes "GC669010,GC669011,GC669012,GC669013,GC669014,GC669015,GC669016,GC669017,GC669018,GC669019,GC669001,GC669002,GC669003,GC669004,GC669005,GC669006,GC669007,GC669008,GC669009,AC669001,GC669047,GC669052,RN669001,ER855036" , newUser == true )
then
    f1.setDiscountAmt( 1000.0 );
    f1.setDiscountPercentage( 0.0 );end
```

In case of rule failure, I want to know which specific condition caused this rule to fail.

Comment: What you have to do in order to know which condition(s) is (are) not met is to have each checked individually. You won't be able to do this using the out-of-the-box guided decision tables. Although one could surely build a system for generating the required rules.

Comment: Do you have any references for the same. Can I write separate rules for each condition manually in different .drl file? In such case how would I get values from decision table cell?

Comment: Section 2.4 in engage.redhat.com/forms/rule-design-patterns discusses your problem. - If you want to access a spreadsheet for obtaining the data you'll have to write the code for doing it. A library for getting the contents of a cell is used in Drools; you can learn how to do that from that code.

Comment: Maybe a Test Scenario can be an option for you, did you check with that?